# how do i assign a class to the checkbox

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I have a piece of code which works perfectly the way it has been written. It produces a checkbox when viewed on a website.

```
  <?=form_checkbox('heart_rate', 'yes', sel_checkbox($admission['heart_rate'], $observation[0]->heart_rate))?> <?=form_label('Heart Rate')?>
```

I would like to know how to give the checkbox a class called mainobservations without altering the other properties.

i tried

```
  <?php $data = array('class'=> 'mainobservations' );?>



<?=form_checkbox($data,'heart_rate', 'yes', sel_checkbox($admission['heart_rate'], $observation[0]->heart_rate))?> <?=form_label('Heart Rate')?>
```

but this did not work so any suggestions on how to arrange the code?

Comment: You will need to show the code for the function form_checkbox() / Edit: Idan spotted its CI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the other values as well as the class in an array and use that:

```
$data = array(
    'name'        => 'heart_rate',
    'class'       => 'mainobservations',
    'value'       => 'yes',
    'checked'     => sel_checkbox($admission['heart_rate'], $observation[0]->heart_rate)
    );

form_checkbox($data);
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html